# Running Linux and Windows containers together on Windows Server 2019

Tags: docker, hyper-v, windows-server-2019, containers

I am using docker EE latest version on my windows server 2019 host and I have nested virtualization enabled(as my windows server 2019 is a VM) and also I installed Hyper-V.

I want to run linux and windows containers together, I tried running ubuntu container but its not working an giving below error message.

```
C:> docker run -d --isolation=hyperv ubuntu:latest
"no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"
```

Is it possible to run linux container on windows server host using isolation=hyperv flag?

If yes, please let me know if any other configuration or steps I need to perform to achieve this( I have Hyper-V and containers feature enabled on my windows server host)

Please suggest if there is any resolution or this is possible to achieve or not.

Answer (score 4):

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/running-docker-windows-and-linux-containers-simultaneously/

As this post indicates, such a feature is still experimental. So you have to let your Docker engine runs in experimental mode, or you receive an error such as

```
> docker pull --platform=linux ubuntu
"--platform" is only supported on a Docker daemon with experimental features enabled
```

To enable Docker engine experimental mode, you can change Docker daemon configuration file in Docker Desktop Community edition,

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": true
}
```

[image]

Not quite sure what's the equivalent steps for Docker EE, but surely you can find it out.